# Does a function get called twice when put inside a conditional with an and/or?

Tags: c, function, if-statement, conditional-statements

For example, if I have this:

```
int i = 0;  // global variable (just for example... I understand these are usually frowned upon)

int foo()
{
    i++;
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    if (foo() == 2 || foo() == 1) {
       printf("hello\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My question is will this code execute the same as below?

```
int i = 0;  // global variable (just for example... I understand these are usually frowned upon)

int foo()
{
    i++;
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    int rv = foo();
    if (rv == 2 || rv == 1) {
       printf("hello\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I ran it, it did make a difference. My thoughts on why this is the case are the first example will not print "hello" because it calls the foo() function twice. The first time it calls it will return 1 and 1 != 2 so it goes to the second part of the or but that part returns 2 and 2 != 1 so the condition is false. The second example only calls it once and stores the return value in a variable so that same value is compared against both parts of the or statement, 1 != 2, but 1 == 1 so it does step into the if statement. I am curious as to which is the correct way to go about this or if there are certain compilers where the optimizer makes these execute the same.

Furthermore, I am write a multithreaded program and I feel like it can be very dangerous to do something similar to the second example as storing the return value in a variable and then comparing that variable to your conditions isn't atomic. I assume the first example is atomic in that both parts of the or in the if statement are carried out before the thread gives control up.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: What happened when you ran it?

Comment: oops I'll edit the post to reflect that

Comment: And perhaps, add some output statements to foo so that you can see how many times it gets called.

Comment: Are you trying to explore how the language works? Is there a real programming problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the multithreading concerns:

> I assume the first example is atomic in that both parts of the or in the if statement are carried out before the thread gives control up.

This is not true. The thread could be preempted at any time during the execution of that `if` (during any instruction in the generated machine code).

Comment: Oh wow, so even the conditional statement isn't atomic. I understand the whole if statement isn't atomic but I thought the evaluation of the conditional was. Thanks for clarifying Andrew!

Answer (score 5):

These are not equivalent code snippets. In the second code snippet function `foo` will be called only once in statement

```
int rv = foo();
```

In the first code snippet function `foo` can be called in general case either one or two times depending on return values of the function

```
if (foo() == 2 || foo() == 1) {
```

For this particular case function  `foo` will be called twice and the result of the condition will be `false` After the first call the function will return 1. 1 is not equal to 2. So the function will be called the second time. It will return 2 and again 2 is not equal to 1. So the result of the condition will be `false`.

In the second code snippet the condition will be equal to `true`

In the first code snippet the result value of i will be equal to 2 while in the second code snippet the result value of i will be equal to 1.

So the code snippets differ in the result value of the condition and the result value of global variable i.

Which way of writing the code is correct depends on your intention. As you did not say what you are trying to achieve it is difficult to answer.

Comment: Thanks, Vlad. This is exactly what I thought was happening. Any comments on the MT part of my post?